How can I fix the lines in my 3D engine from glitching when they go offscreen in Java?
I'm coding a 3D Engine in Java, and I've noticed that whenever an object goes out of the camera's view, the lines go all crazy all over the screen. The object also reappears onscreen, but upside-down.
Here's the code I used to project 3D points onto the screen:
public double[] projPoint(double xi, double yi, double zi){
    double x = xi * (gp.focalLength / zi);
    double y = yi * (gp.focalLength / zi);
    double[] out = {x, y};
    return out;
}

Here's an image of the bug:


Now what your doing is pretty complex but here are a couple of things:
a) are you using a library to get the graphics or is it by scratch
b) are you using clac 3 math to get this done
c) is this like a raycaster (aka fake 3d)?
d) is there any relevant part of code that you can share
e) did you try using debugging to get the position of the item
f) did you limit the user so that the item cant go off screen?

you have points that go behind the camera's origin, right?

@ChristophRackwitz yes I think so

@TijilSaka a) it's not a library, it's made from scratch b) no c) no it is real 3d d) I did share some of the code e) no f) limiting that would be impossible

@Earthmars643 then go and debug it with debugging statements printing out the position

what happens if you have to project a point that's behind the camera, not in front of it? what happens if you have two points, one behind and one in front, and a line going between both?

@ChristophRackwitz if I project a point that's behind the camera it appears inverted in front of the camera, and if i have two points in between the camera border, the one that's in front is perfectly fine, and the other one is seemingly in a random spot causing the lines to go crazy

You are missing the frustum culling. Specifically you need to clip each line with the near plane, like that:
public double[] projPoint(double xi, double yi, double zi) { // also return z
    double x = xi * (gp.focalLength / zi);
    double y = yi * (gp.focalLength / zi);
    double z = zi; // Keeping z to use for clipping
    double[] out = {x, y, z};
    return out;
}
public double[] interpolate(double[] p1, double[] p2, double z0) {
    double t = (z0 - p1[2]) / (p2[2] - p1[2]);
    double x = p1[0] + t * (p2[0] - p1[0]);
    double y = p1[1] + t * (p2[1] - p1[1]);
    return new double[] {x, y, nearPlane};
}

public boolean clip(double[] p1, double[] p2) {
    if (p1[2] >= gp.nearPlane && p2[2] >= gp.nearPlane) {
        return true; // Both points are in the visible region, no clipping needed
    }
    if (p1[2] < gp.nearPlane && p2[2] < gp.nearPlane) {
        return false; // Both points are outside, clip the line entirely
    }
    if (p1[2] < gp.nearPlane) {
        p1 = interpolate(p1, p2, gp.nearPlane); // Move p1 to the near plane
    } else if (p2[2] < gp.nearPlane) {
        p2 = interpolate(p1, p2, gp.nearPlane); // Move p2 to the near plane
    }
    return true; 
}

You should call clip for each line.
Note that even it you insist not to use a 3d rendering library like openGl (with also gpu acceleration), at least you should use (or code yourself) a 3d library like JOML with objects like Vector3 and Matrix4x4. Then, for example, interpolate will look like { return p1.lerp(p2, (z0-p1.z)/(p2.z-p1.z)); }
